# Custom Validation Message in Laravel with custom attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-formrequest

I am creating a rule for my validation on my laravel app.

i wrote my rules below

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|string',
            'taxonomies' => 'required|array',
            'taxonomies.*.id' => 'required|string|exists:taxonomies,id', 
            'taxonomies.*.values' => 'required|array|min:2',
            'taxonomies.*.values.*' => 'required',
            'currency' => 'required|string',
            'client_budget' => 'required|numeric',
        ];
    }
```

in `'taxonomies.*.values.*'` i will be expecting an array which every key on array['values'] should not be empty
eg.
this is what i expect

```
[
            'taxonomies' => [
                '0' => [
                    'id' => 7,
                    'values' => [
                        'key1' => 'own value',
                        'key2' => 'own value',
                        'key3' => 'own value'
                    ],
                ],
                '1' => [
                    'id' => 12,
                    'values' => [
                        'key1' => 'own value',
                        'key2' => 'own value',
                        'key3' => 'own value'
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

so if by any change a key is missing it should show an error
this is working fine
but When showing error message for 'taxonomies.*.values.*', is display as

```
"The taxonomies.0.values.key1 field is required."
```

i want it to show something link this

```
The key1 value is required at array 0
```

How will i achieve this?

Comment: so there is no error with validation rules but you want to change the message only. Right?

Comment: you will need to iterate the `taxonomies` and write a custom message for each required message. you can create a generic function to make the error message.

Answer (score 3):

You can passed in a 2nd and 3rd params during validation for message and attribute value

e.i.

```
$request->validate(
    [
        'taxonomies.*.values.*' => 'required'
    ],
    [
        'taxonomies.*.values.*' => 'The :attribute value is required at array :index'
    ],
    [
        'taxonomies.0.values.key1' => 'key1'
    ]
);
```

and you'll get error like this

`The key1 value is required at array 0`

However, since you doing dynamic array, I can only think of manipulating the attributes array based on your request content.

Something like this

```
public function store( Request $request  ) {
        
    $attributes = [];
    
    foreach ($request->input('taxonomies') as $index => $values) {
        $valValues = $values['values'];
        foreach ($valValues as $key => $value) {
            $attributes['taxonomies.'.$index.'.values.'.$key] = $key;
        }
    }
    
    $request->validate(
        [
            'taxonomies' => 'required|array',
            'taxonomies.*.id' => 'required', 
            'taxonomies.*.values' => 'required|array|min:2',
            'taxonomies.*.values.*' => 'required'
        ],
        [
            'taxonomies.*.values.*' => 'The :attribute value is required at array :index'
        ],
        $attributes,
        
    );

    //valid request, continue;
}
```

or if you are using Form Request Validation, you can add `messages` and `attributes` method in your request validation class.

e.i.

```
// Your validation rules
public function rules() {...}

public function messages() {
    return [
        'taxonomies.*.values.*' => 'The :attribute value is required at array :index'
    ];
}

//This should cover all attributes taxonomies.*.values.* present in your request and replaces it with the last key
public function attributes() {
    $attributes = [];

    if ( $this->taxonomies && is_array( $this->taxonomies ) )  {

        foreach ($this->taxonomies as $index => $values) {
            $valValues = $values['values'] ?? null;

            if( !$valValues || !is_array( $valValues ) )
                continue;

            foreach ($valValues as $key => $value) {
                $attributes['taxonomies.'.$index.'.values.'.$key] = $key;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $attributes;
}
```